# How to generate an url based in title with token and pathauto module?

Tags: 7, tokens, path-aliases

I have this pattern in admin/config/search/path/patterns: region/[node:title].

I need in a custom module regenerate the same string this Token/Pathauto does (In fact , I still not get who works in this conversion).

The idea is to create a function in my module like:

```
    $node2 = node_load(1013); // With the NID given, get node.
    $title_of_node2 = $node2->title; // Extract the title
    $URL = TOKEN_OR_PATHAUTO_FUNCTION_THAT_GENERATE_MY_CLEAN_SEO_URL(title_of_node2)
```

With the $URL I will construct an url pattern to my new node before I save it, instead of editing the admin/config/search/path one by one, because it is not one page.

I tried to catch the url with `drupal_get_path_alias` but in the moment I generate everthing with a hook, this does not return the result I see in admin/config/search/path, after the process is done.

The ideia is generate what is going to be generated to put in other place after the all the process is done.

I found [_pathauto_set_alias](http://api.drupalize.me/api/drupal/function/_pathauto_set_alias/7) and [pathauto_create_alias](http://api.drupalize.me/api/drupal/function/pathauto_create_alias/7) but could not find a way to call/implement from my own module to find if this does what I am looking for...

Comment: Why don't you generate all path after setting patern at your given admin section ?

Comment: In the admin section a create a pattern based on content type. But the pages that I generate can be or can´t be in this situation. Right now is this: `node/id/the-title-of-custom-page-create-in-my-module`, but I want the alias to be `region/region-of-east-side/the-title-of-custom-page-create-in-my-module`. If this is from another place will be: `region/region-whatever/the-title...`